# exporting data from influxdb to dataframes and then store it in mf4 files using python

Tags: python, dataframe, influxdb, mdf

[image]i need to store a huge amount of data from influxdb to mf4 files to run it in famos, so i get the data from influxdb using query and I get it as dataframes and then I am trying to save it to the mf4 file but every time i am getting this  error 'DatetimeTZDtype object has no attribute byteorder'
I think the problem is from the index in the dataframes which is the timestamp returned from influxdb, i tried to convert it using many ways but i am still getting the same error, any help on how i should store these dataframes to mf4??

```
result=client.query(query,chucked=True)
mdf=MDF()
retconverted=result.convert_dtypes()
mdf.append(retconverted)
mdf.save('test.mf4', overwrite=True, times_as_date=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting DateTime to UNIX timestamp

```
 import time
 import dateutil.parser
 import member.models import Member
 date_joined = member.date_joined
 dt = dateutil.parser.parse(date_joined)
 print int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
```

If you can share how your date shows by printing it will help to understand the question more.

Comment: the picture i added contains the result of printing 'result'

Comment: whats is the name of the column contain date and time i.e temperature data contains 33.5 on first row and so on.

Comment: it has no name, it is the index column in the dataframe

Comment: What asammdf version do you use? Please add the complete error traceback message so I can start debugging the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try converting time to to_datetime

```
import pandas as pd
result['time'] = pd.to_datetime(result['time'])

#If you want you can change your time format like:
result['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time, errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```